# log association for task spanning multiple threads

Tags: java, logging, log4j

The task in my software involves several steps where each step may or may not execute in different threads. Each step has some log and I use log4j as logging service.

A headache problem is it's hard to associate logs printed by different threads to the task they belongs to. In single thread mode, the thread name is a good indicator, but it doesn't work in multiple threads mode. I don't want to pass a task indicator through threads as it's annoying and will burden programmer.

I wonder anybody faced the same problem and had a good solution? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for [log4j's documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/NDCvsMDC) on MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) and NDC (Nested Diagnostic Context). Below is the excerpt from [this article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/08/07/log4j.html?page=3)

> Nested Diagnostic Context (NDC) and Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)
>   help in situations where one application is involved in simultaneously
>   serving multiple clients, and you are interested in separating or
>   distingushing log content from each of these multiple clients. A Web
>   application is a really good example of such a situation.
>
> So how do we separate or distinguish content from multiple clients? By
>   marking each log statement with client-specific information. This, in
>   a typical Web application, could include, among other things, the
>   client's IP address, which is readily available to the servlet
>   container. So, in NDC, you push this information on a stack when
>   entering a context, and pop it when leaving that context. log4j uses
>   this context-specific information when writing to the appender, if in
>   your associated layout, you use the %x conversion pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes org.apache.log4j.MDC and org.apache.log4j.NDC which are created for this purpose.
Just refer Javadocs: [NDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html) and [MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html)